# Wordpress slider for featured post on homepage

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress

This what I am trying to do - source - http://www.torontostandard.com/

[image: Scrollable]

Is there any plugin for this look and feel ?

Code im using this time to fetch posts with featured tag.

However it would be better if I can loop using jquery, but unable to find any tutorial on this :(

```
<?php query_posts('tag=featured'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>  
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

PS- Googled a lot for this plugin but unable to find any

Answer (score 0):

I always find that if I want to steal a jquery plugin from a site I just look at the source and google the js files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/libraries/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
```

however I always just build my own but that's me.

Comment: I checked though and was just revolving around anythingslider..but thx let me chk this

Comment: Checked it but not finding any good tut on this for implementing the functionality..let me know if you have something regarding this

Comment: it is anythingSlider ... and hey, there is even a [wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/anythingslider-for-wordpress/) for it.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider thx..I already checked that..contains around more than +90 errors for the latest version :(

Comment: this is why I don't use plugins on WP :)